# Package Loading error

Tags: python, r, excel

Not sure why xlsx package not loading into R (It has been installed and downloaded without any error).

```
install.packages("xlsx")
library(xlsx)

Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 3.4.3
```

Please assist

Comment: Do you have java installed on your computer ? Does it fits your R version (is it 32 bits or 64 bits ?)

Comment: Yes , java installed and its 64 bits

Comment: Also, While using below its not loading, it seems there is a problem with Rjava within R.   install.packages("rJava")
library(rJava)   Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’ in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env):
 lazy-load database 'C:/Users/RAMIT PAUL/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rJava/R/rJava.rdb' is corrupt
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.4.3 
2: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall it ?

Comment: It was required the R studio version to be changed into 34 bit default. It worked .